# Exclude certain fields in HABTM find()

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm using CakeDC Tags plugin and I would like to find Tags in my Books Model.

In my Books controller, I have an index() method which returns paginated results. Currently, my index() method looks like this.

```
function index() {
    $this-Book>recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'fields' => array('Book.id','Book.name'),
        'conditions' => array('Book.status' => 1),
        'order' => array('Book.id' => 'DESC'),
        'limit' => 10
    );
    $books = $this->paginate($this->Book);
    $this->set('books', $books);
}
```

When I do a debug, these are my results:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Book] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [name] => A randomly random book
                    [tags] => 
                )

        )
)
```

If I raise the recursiveness to 1 instead of 0, the tags array will be populated and the debug output are as follow:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Book] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [name] => A randomly random book
                    [tags] => wicked
                )
            [Tag] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4f30d76a-20dc-44ce-943c-048c98b7a787
                            [identifier] => 
                            [name] => wicked
                            [keyname] => wicked
                            [weight] => 0
                            [created] => 2012-02-07 18:48:58
                            [modified] => 2012-02-07 18:48:58
                            [Tagged] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4f30d76a-f55c-4ab7-b076-048c98b7a787
                                    [foreign_key] => 53
                                    [tag_id] => 4f30d76a-20dc-44ce-943c-048c98b7a787
                                    [model] => Book
                                    [language] => en-us
                                    [created] => 2012-02-07 18:48:58
                                    [modified] => 2012-02-07 18:48:58
                                )

                        )
                )

        )
)
```

Raising the recursiveness does the job quite well. However, CakePHP returned everything including the created and modified date field. Is there anyway to get CakePHP to populate the $book['Book']['tags'] array only  but not the [Tag] and [Tagged] array? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know this particular plugin, but the usual way to get a finer grained control of the data that is retrieved from the DB is with the `Containable` behaviour: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1323/Containable

Once you add it to your `Book` model this is what you would write to retrieve only the names and ids of `Tag`s:

```
$this-Book>recursive = -1;
$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array('Book.id','Book.name'),
    'contain' => array(
        'Tag'=>array('id','name'),
    ),
    'conditions' => array('Book.status' => 1),
    'order' => array('Book.id' => 'DESC'),
    'limit' => 10
);
```

Comment: Hi Joni, Thanks for the tip. I had a gut feeling earlier on that Containable would definitely be the right place to start. Thank you very much.